# Oracle Apex Import multiple exported files at once in application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have exported my oracle apex application to take its back up.
It has multiple application files, page files, ui files etc. My apex version is 20.1 and i am using apex.oracle.com.

If i need to import this same application again, do i have to import all the individual pages one by one like they have been exported or is there a way to import them all at once?

I tried importing the zip file but its not working.

Please suggest a workaround to upload all files at once as there are around 40 page files apart from application files, user interface files, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the export files is a separate script containing a number of pl/sql blocks. You could try to contatenate them together into a single script, upload and run that. However there is a size limit to scripts so you'll probably have to use more than one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, that won't work on apex.oracle.com.

I was thinking of Apex SQL Workshop, running multiple scripts at once (sequentially). Why? Because those export files are .SQL files so you can run each of them *as a script*. However, there's no such option.

If you load it into SQL Commands, it won't work because of invalid/unrecognized SQL*Plus commands such as `whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode rollback`.

If it weren't for apex.oracle.com but your "local" Oracle database, the one you have access to and can use SQL*Plus, you could write a script that calls other scripts, but - as that's not your case, no use of it.

Therefore, I think that you'll have to import each of those files manually, one by one.

Comment: I have another question in case you can answer, else will raise separate thread. I restored my application with one of the back ups but realised the backup had errors. Now i wish to restore it back. is it possible?

Comment: Maybe. Try to export the application using its "**As of ... minutes ago**". Check help text next to that option to find more information.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you chose to export as zip?

You could just do a normal export, which will give you a single file with your application and most everything it needs all in one place and very easy to import when needed.

If supporting objects are a concern, create install scripts that build your tables, triggers, etc. and make sure to choose "Yes" or "Yes, and install automatically" in the "Export Supporting Object Definitions" drop down.

You can still download the zip too and stuff that into version control if that is needed, but for ease of restoring an application, the "normal" single file way is far easier to manage.